# Select RadioButton Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On the website : https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/ I try to set some filters to collect data. I want to set the filter time on : "Display time only" and the filter importance on : 2 and 3 bulls. I tried the following script but none of the Radio button are interactable.

```
base_url = "https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, port=5007)
driver.get(base_url)

# expand filters
driver.find_element_by_id("filterStateAnchor").click()

Radio_bull2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='importance2']")
Radio_bull2.click()

Radio_bull3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='importance3']")
Radio_bull3.click()

Radio_time = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='timetimeOnly']")
Radio_time.click()
```

I would greatly appreciate some help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To click on dynamic element like `Display time only` and `bull2 & bull3` induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'filterStateAnchor'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'timetimeOnly'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'importance2'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'importance3'))).click()
```

You need to add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```